# Adding items to a listview in a specific order

Tags: vb.net, listview

```
    If Not m_Batchs Is Nothing Then
        For Each Batch In m_Batchs
            newListItem = lstWsJobs.Items.Add(Batch.Id.ToString)
            With newListItem
                .Name = Batch.Id.ToString()
                .SubItems.Add(Batch.JobId.ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(Batch.Complete.ToString)
                .SubItems.Add(Batch.User)
                .SubItems.Add(Batch.Time.ToString)
            End With
        Next
    End If
```

I have this list view (which is working fine) and i want to find an efficient way of populating it in a specific order, ie by date, by identity etc.

I know i can use linq but as i understand this is inefficient. If m_batchs is a large list of objects then i will looping through this list many, many time (as linq behind the scenes loops through the object collection).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ is not inefficient in general but almost always it's easier to read and faster to implement, change and extend. Also, does it really matter if one approach is 1 millisecond faster on 1000 iterations?

So i assume that `Batch` is a custom type and `m_Batchs` is a `List<Batch>`:

```
// order by date 
var query = m_Batchs.OrderBy(b => b.Time);
// order by identity 
query = m_Batchs.OrderBy(b => b.ID);
// ...
```

Measure the difference between this simple LINQ query and your custom implementation.

Edit: Sorry, that was C#

```
Dim batchByTime = m_Batchs.OrderBy(Function(b) b.Time);
Dim batchByID = m_Batchs.OrderBy(Function(b) b.ID);
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. Yes your assumptions are correct. I though that linq was to be used more as a filter rather than a 'sorter'. I will have a quick try to see if this works with our larger collections/lists.

Comment: Keep in mind that LINQ performs worse while running in Debug mode.  Always do LINQ performance tests in Release mode.